# Alternative to WMI when querying for hardware information?

Tags: c#, performance, wmi

I've been working with WMI for the purposes of building a system fingerprint and it... works... but only *just*. It takes forever, and the worst part is that it's at application startup, so minutes pass before anything else happens.

Herein is how I am building the system finger print:

```
private static async Task<string> GetHash( string s ) {
    byte[ ] b = await Task.Run( ( ) => IdLib.AscEnc.GetBytes( s ) );
    return await IdLib.GetHexString( IdLib.CSP.ComputeHash( b ) );
}

private static async Task<string> GetHexString( byte[ ] b ) {
    string s = string.Empty;
    await Task.Run( ( ) => {
        b.ToList( ).ForEach( by => {
            int[ ] n = new int[ ] { 0, 0, 0 };
            n[0] = ( int )by;
            n[1] = n[0] & 15;
            n[2] = ( n[0] >> 4 ) & 15;
                s += n[1] > 9
            ? ( ( char )( n[1] - 10 + ( int )'A' ) ).ToString( )
            : n[1].ToString( );
                s += n[2] > 9
            ? ( ( char )( n[2] - 10 + ( int )'A' ) ).ToString( )
            : n[2].ToString( );
                if ( ( s.Length - s.Count( c => c == '-' ) ) % 4 == 0 )
                s += '-';
        } );
    } );
    return s.TrimEnd( '-' );
}

private static async Task<string> ID( string wmiClass, string wmiProperty, string wmiMustBeTrue ) {
    string result = string.Empty;
    List<ManagementObject> MOC = new ManagementClass( wmiClass ).GetInstances( ).Cast<ManagementObject>( ).ToList( );
    foreach ( ManagementObject MO in MOC ) {
        if ( wmiMustBeTrue.Equals( string.Empty ) || MO[wmiMustBeTrue].ToString( ).Equals( "True" ) )
            if ( result.Equals( string.Empty ) )
                try {
                    result = await Task.Run( ( ) => MO[wmiProperty].ToString( ) );
                    break;
                } catch { }
    }
    return result;
}

private static async Task<string> ID( string wmiClass, string wmiProperty ) {
    return await IdLib.ID( wmiClass, wmiProperty, string.Empty );
}

private static async Task<string> GetCPUID( ) {
    string r = await IdLib.ID( "Win32_Processor", "UniqueId" );
    if ( r.Equals( string.Empty ) )
        r = await IdLib.ID( "Win32_Processor", "ProcessorId" );
    if ( r.Equals( string.Empty ) )
        r = await IdLib.ID( "Win32_Processor", "Name" );
    if ( r.Equals( string.Empty ) )
        r = await IdLib.ID( "Win32_Processor", "Manufacturer" );
    r += IdLib.ID( "Win32_Processor", "MaxClockSpeed" );
    return await IdLib.GetHash( r );
}

private static async Task<string> GetBiosID( ) {
    return await IdLib.GetHash(
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_BIOS", "Manufacturer" ) +
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_BIOS", "SMBIOSBIOSVersion" ) +
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_BIOS", "IdentificationCode" ) +
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_BIOS", "SerialNumber" ) +
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_BIOS", "ReleaseDate" ) +
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_BIOS", "Version" )
    );
}

private static async Task<string> GetHDDID( ) {
    return await IdLib.GetHash(
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_DiskDrive", "Model" ) +
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_DiskDrive", "Manufacturer" ) +
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_DiskDrive", "Signature" ) +
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_DiskDrive", "TotalHeads" ) );
}

private static async Task<string> GetMOBOID( ) {
    return await IdLib.GetHash(
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_BaseBoard", "Model" ) +
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_BaseBoard", "Manufacturer" ) +
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_BaseBoard", "Name" ) +
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_BaseBoard", "SerialNumber" ) );
}

private static async Task<string> GetVGAID( ) {
    return await IdLib.GetHash(
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_VideoController", "DriverVersion" ) +
        await IdLib.ID( "Win32_VideoController", "Name" ) );
}

private static async Task<string> GetMACID( ) {
    return await IdLib.GetHash( await IdLib.ID( "Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration", "MacAddress", "IPEnabled" ) );
}
```

Acknowledging that there is probably a lot wrong here, my first and foremost concern is that the `ID(string, string, string)` method is taking ***forever*** to execute, and that's just not acceptable. Does there exist an alternative to using WMI for obtaining such low level information? If necessary, I'm willing to go as far as constructing a C/C++ library to speed this up...

### EDIT 1

It has been suggested that the bulk of the time being consumed happens when creating a `ManagementClass` object. Instead of that I have opted for going with something a `WqlObjectQuery`:

```
private static async Task<string> ID( string wmiClass, string wmiProperty, string wmiMustBeTrue ) {
    Task<string> T = Task.Run( ( ) => {
        Stopwatch SW = new Stopwatch( );
        WqlObjectQuery Q = new WqlObjectQuery(
            "SELECT " +
                wmiProperty +
            " FROM "
                + wmiClass +
            ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( wmiMustBeTrue ) ? "" : "WHERE " + wmiMustBeTrue + " = True" ) );
        ManagementObjectSearcher MOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher( Q );
        SW.Start( );
        ManagementObjectCollection MOC = MOS.Get( );
        while ( MOC.GetEnumerator( ).MoveNext( ) )
            if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( MOC.GetEnumerator( ).Current[wmiProperty].ToString( ) ) ) {
                SW.Stop( );
                Console.WriteLine( "Querying " + wmiProperty + " of " + wmiClass + " took " + SW.Elapsed.ToString( ) );
                return MOC.GetEnumerator( ).Current[wmiProperty].ToString( );
            }
        return null;
    });
    await T;
    if ( T.Exception == null )
        return T.Result;
    else {
        Console.WriteLine( "Exception in ID Method Function : wmiClass : " + wmiClass + "; wmiPriperty : " + wmiProperty + ";" );
        Exception E = T.Exception;
        while ( E != null ) {
            Console.WriteLine( E.Message );
            Console.WriteLine( E.StackTrace );
            E = E.InnerException;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I've been noticing, while watching the debug output, that there continues to be these first chance exceptions thrown, telling me that there is a NullReferenceException... somewhere... it's quite irritating. I enabled breaking on every exception type and it's led me to the conclusion that it's been getting thrown when I was trying to do the following :

```
return new ManagementObjectSearcher(/*Direct String Query*/).Get( ).Cast<ManagementObject>( ).First( )[wmiProperty].ToString( );
```

This made me think that I was probably doing too much, so I switched it to the present incarnation of the function which is now throwing another exception (first chance, I think), telling me that the `MOC.GetEnumerator( ).Current[wmiProperty].ToString( )` is throwing an exception because something is in an invalid state. I think it's because I need to get the enumerator into it's own variable maybe... but that makes no sense either because it's passed by reference, so having a variable of `ManagementObjectEnumerator Foo = MOC.GetEnumerator` should be exactly the same (although for brevity less ideal) than just calling `MOC.GetEnumerator( )`... It may also be that the object within the property I am querying is null and trying to make it into a string is breaking things... more to come I'm sure...

### EDIT 2

Okay, so it was because I wasn't instantiating the enumerator. Third incarnation of the function:

```
private static async Task<string> ID( string wmiClass, string wmiProperty, string wmiMustBeTrue ) {
    Task<string> T = Task.Run( ( ) => {
        Stopwatch SW = new Stopwatch( );
        SW.Start( );
        ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator MOE = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
            "SELECT " +
                wmiProperty +
            " FROM "
                + wmiClass +
            ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( wmiMustBeTrue ) ? "" : "WHERE " + wmiMustBeTrue + " = True" ) ).Get( ).GetEnumerator( );
        while ( MOE.MoveNext( ) )
            if ( MOE.Current[wmiProperty] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty( MOE.Current[wmiProperty].ToString( ) ) ) {
                SW.Stop( );
                Console.WriteLine( "Querying " + wmiProperty + " of " + wmiClass + " took " + SW.Elapsed.ToString( ) );
                return MOE.Current[wmiProperty].ToString( );
            }
        SW.Stop( );
        Console.WriteLine( "Querying " + wmiProperty + " of " + wmiClass + " took " + SW.Elapsed.ToString( ) + "; returned null." );
        return null;
    });
    await T;
    if ( T.Exception == null )
        return T.Result;
    else {
        Console.WriteLine( "Exception in ID Method Function : wmiClass : " + wmiClass + "; wmiPriperty : " + wmiProperty + ";" );
        Exception E = T.Exception;
        while ( E != null ) {
            Console.WriteLine( E.Message );
            Console.WriteLine( E.StackTrace );
            E = E.InnerException;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I suppose that's reasonable and makes sense as the function GetEnumerator( ) may return an instance rather than a reference...

Comment: There is no language C/C++. Please do not add all tags just because they start with `C`.

Comment: If I'm understanding ID right, it's looking for the specified property value of the first WMI object that meets the criterion (the property specified by wmiMustBeTrue has value "True"), right?

Comment: @JerryFederspiel Yes.

Comment: You appear to be re-getting the relevant ManagementObjects for every call to ID.  Something to try: let ID take a params string[] of properties, then fetch the ManagementObject you're interested in and grab all the properties from it.

Comment: Additionally to the @JerryFederspiel suggestion, don't use this code `ManagementClass( wmiClass ).GetInstances`  to get the properties  because you are getting all the properties of the WMI class, instead build the WQL sentence on the fly. that will improve the performance.

Comment: @RRUZ Working on that; I only ever need to query a single property anyway, and my research has led me in that direction. I am, however, encountering a new issue that's probably about as frustrating...